# How to fix On error Facebook log in result in android

Tags: facebook-login

when I click on the button of sign in the window of choosing facebook profile appears ! but once I confirm the the profile the app crashes . And by using logs I figured out that the register call is not successful so I'have a facebook exeception which causes error , how can i find the source error ?

```
facebookSignInButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    // Login
    Log.i(TAG,"CLICKED")
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"))
    Log.i(TAG,"Permissions")

    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
        object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Facebook token: " + loginResult.accessToken.token)
                startActivity(Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java))
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Facebook onCancel.")
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Facebook onError.") 
                // This part is written in run console

            }
        })
})

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    callbackManager!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Log.i(TAG,"RESULT"+resultCode.toString()) // this retrun -1 
    Log.i(TAG,"REQUEST"+requestCode.toString())
}
```

I expect starting a new activity while logging.

Comment: Reformatted code section

Answer (score 0):

After printing the msg error the problem is in the hash key it doesn't match any key stored !
so instead if using line cmnds I just use this code in my on create function and then copy the hash key into your facebook developer app

```
val packageName = this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()

           val info : PackageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
           for ( signature in info.signatures) {
               var md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
               md.update(signature.toByteArray())
               val hashKey = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), 0)
               Log.i(TAG,"HADHKEEEY"+hashKey)
           }
           Log.i(TAG,"NAAAMEE"+packageName)
```